# Get model count in ajax response returning Partial View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a method named `Issues` in `Issues` controller through ajax.

```
var url = "@(Url.Action("Issues", "Issues"))";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: issue,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (evt) {
        $('#filteredDataList').html(evt);
    },
});
```

And in my controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Issues(IssuesModel issue)
{
    var model = allIssuesList.OrderBy(p => p.ID).ToList();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Issues/_LoadMoreIssues.cshtml", model.Take(20));
}
```

What I need is a way to get the model count in the success response of the ajax call, so i can do the following:

```
success: function (evt) {
    $('#filteredDataList').html(evt);
    var modelCount = ???
    if (modelCount > (20)) {
        $("#loadMore").show().fadeIn(2000);
    }
},...
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Why in the world are you getting all records and materializing it to memeory when you only want 20. Remove the`.ToList() in you query. In the `_LoadMoreIssues` view, add a hidden input (say) `<input type="hidden" id="count" value="@model.Count() />` and then you can use `var modelCount = $(evt).find('@count').val();` Alternatively `$(evt).find(someElement).length;` where `someElement` is something that is rendered for each item in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning a model to the ajax call, you're returning html.

You can include any information you like in the html and read it from there.

First, add a viewmodel to include your additional information:

```
 public class MoreIssuesViewModel 
 {
     public IList<Order> Orders { get;set; }
     public int Total { get;set; }
 }
```

Use this from the controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Issues(IssuesModel issue)
{
    var data = allIssuesList.OrderBy(p => p.ID).ToList()
    var model = new MoreIssuesViewModel 
    {
        Orders = data.Take(20),
        Total = Orders.Count()
    }
    return PartialView("~/Views/Issues/_LoadMoreIssues.cshtml", model);
}
```

Then in your view, store the new information somewhere (example)

```
@model MoreIssuesViewModel
<table data-total='@Model.Total'>
  <tbody>    
      @foreach(var order in Model.Orders) {
         <td>....</td>
      }
```

You can then read this from the `success`

```
success: function (evt) {
    $('#filteredDataList').html(evt);
    var modelCount = $('#filteredDataList table').data("total")
    if (modelCount > (20)) {
        $("#loadMore").show().fadeIn(2000);
    }
},...
```

Comment: I am getting undefined value for modelCount in `window.alert("model count: " + modelCount);`

Comment: Well, that all depends on how you're building your partial view, which you've not provided in the question.  You'll need to *adapt the general principals provided here* to match your specific scenario.  See @StephenMuecke 's comment for an alternative method to pass the details (in a hidden input) - but the same principal applies

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. I was missing something. Now it's working as expected. thanks :)